# Extract row index from a data frame based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

Assume I have a `df` like this

```
    v1   v2   v3
     1     3   3
     1     3    2
```

And I'd like to extract row index where `v1=1` and `v3=2` (so I'm expecting 2 as a result)

I don't want to `subset` the data or to `filter` it. I tried to use `grep`, but I have been able to do it only for one condition at a time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: which((v1==1) & (v3==2))

Comment: Tks! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

```
rownames(df[v1==1 & v3==2,])
```